Semi-colon separated argument in CMake's `add_custom_command` using the Visual Studio generator
I've been unable to get this very simple piece of CMake to run as expected:
set(FOO baz$<SEMICOLON>bar)

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT whatever
  COMMAND custom-compiler.py --include=${FOO}
)

This is one of the many variations I tried.
My tests included:

Using the VERBATIM flag
Using the COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS flag
Using literal semi-colons
Using escaped semi-colons
Adding double-quotes around the expanded variable
Adding double-quotes when defining the variable
Copy-paste whatever hallucination $LLM gave me

At the end of the day, either the ; are turned into spaces because CMake lists, or they are double-quoted, giving me something like e.g. --include=baz";"bar.
Funniest part of all, this example works otherwise just fine with Ninja, it is only broken when using the Visual Studio generator. Unfortunately, I, for now, need to support this generator.

Would not set(FOO "baz;bar") just work?

Unfortunately not, CMake just assumes FOO is a list, and prints the variable as baz bar with a space in-between. Honestly not even sure this is a CMake problem, given my ninja build works fine. I think I'm going to change or compiler tool, at this point.
